# es6 export of a function doesn't work

Tags: ecmascript-6

I want my module to export multiple functions and numerical constants.
When I import all exported properties of my module I see that functions are not actually imported.

```
//module1.js
const func1 = (a) => {console.log(1)}; 
const func2 = (b) => {console.log(2)}; 
const variable1 = 1;
const variable2 = 2;

export const exp1 = func1;
export const exp2 = func2;
export const exp3 = variable1; 
export const exp4 = variable2;
```

.

```
//anotherFile.js
import * as module1 from './module1';
console.log(JSON.stringify(module1, null, 2));                   // {"module1": {"exp3":1, "exp4":2}}
```

What is the correct way of importing functions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All works!

my problem was in `console.log(JSON.stringify(module1, null, 2));` 
JSON.stringify was cutting off my functions